# parallelizing matrix multiplication through threading and SIMD

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, matrix-multiplication, simd

I am trying to speed up matrix multiplication on multicore architecture. For this end, I try to use threads and SIMD at the same time. But my results are not good. I test speed up over sequential matrix multiplication:

```
void sequentialMatMul(void* params)
{
    cout << "SequentialMatMul started.";
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                X[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\nSequentialMatMul finished.";
}
```

I tried to add threading and SIMD to matrix multiplication as follows:

```
void threadedSIMDMatMul(void* params)
{
    bounds *args = (bounds*)params;
    int lowerBound = args->lowerBound;
    int upperBound = args->upperBound;
    int idx = args->idx;

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = lowerBound; i <upperBound; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j+=4)
            {
                mmx1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&X[i][j]);
                mmx2 = _mm_load_ps1(&A[i][k]);
                mmx3 = _mm_loadu_ps(&B[k][j]);
                mmx4 = _mm_mul_ps(mmx2, mmx3);
                mmx0 = _mm_add_ps(mmx1, mmx4);
                _mm_storeu_ps(&X[i][j], mmx0);
            }
        }
    }
    _endthread();
}
```

And the following section is used for calculating lowerbound and upperbound of each thread:

```
bounds arg[CORES];
for (int part = 0; part < CORES; part++)
{
    arg[part].idx = part;
    arg[part].lowerBound = (N / CORES)*part;
    arg[part].upperBound = (N / CORES)*(part + 1);
}
```

And finally threaded SIMD version is called like this:

```
HANDLE  handle[CORES];      
for (int part = 0; part < CORES; part++)
{
    handle[part] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(threadedSIMDMatMul, 0, (void*)&arg[part]);
}
for (int part = 0; part < CORES; part++)
{
WaitForSingleObject(handle[part], INFINITE);
}
```

The result is as follows:
Test 1:

```
// arrays are defined as follow
float A[N][N];
float B[N][N];
float X[N][N];
N=2048
Core=1//just one thread
```

Sequential time: 11129ms

Threaded SIMD matmul time: 14650ms

Speed up=0.75x

Test 2:

```
//defined arrays as follow
float **A = (float**)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(float), 16);
float **B = (float**)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(float), 16);
float **X = (float**)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(float), 16);
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
    A[k] = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    B[k] = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    X[k] = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
}
N=2048
Core=1//just one thread
```

Sequential time: 15907ms

Threaded SIMD matmul time: 18578ms

Speed up=0.85x

Test 3:

```
//defined arrays as follow
float A[N][N];
float B[N][N];
float X[N][N];
N=2048
Core=2
```

Sequential time: 10855ms

Threaded SIMD matmul time: 27967ms

Speed up=0.38x

Test 4:

```
//defined arrays as follow
float **A = (float**)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(float), 16);
float **B = (float**)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(float), 16);
float **X = (float**)_aligned_malloc(N* sizeof(float), 16);
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
    A[k] = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    B[k] = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    X[k] = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
}
N=2048
Core=2
```

Sequential time: 16579ms

Threaded SIMD matmul time: 30160ms

Speed up=0.51x

**My question: why I don’t get speed up?**

Comment: I'm guessing that the naive implementation of matrix multiplication (which directly uses the definition of the product) does not translate too well to to SIMD. In the first parallelization, the value `A[i][k]` needs to be copied into all four components of the register. The desired entry`X[i][j]` can be expressed as the sum of the products of the `i`-th row of `A` with the `j`-th column of `B`. If `B` would be stored column-wise instead of row-wise, the parallelism could be applied in a more straightforward way and would also be more cache-friendly.

Comment: [openmp-c-matrix-multiplication-run-slower-in-parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634121/openmp-c-matrix-multiplication-run-slower-in-parallel/22637933#22637933)

Comment: When you define arrays rather than pointer to arrays I assume you're using global arrays (if so I would make them static) because the stack is too small for 2048x2048 arrays.

Comment: @Codor . thank you for your comment, of course transposing matrix B can improve result.

Comment: @Zboson yes, in my code arrays are global. thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the times I get building on your algorithm on my four core i7 IVB processor.

```
sequential:         3.42 s
4 threads:          0.97 s
4 threads + SSE:    0.86 s
```

Here are the times on a 2 core P9600 @2.53 GHz which is similar to the OP's E2200 @2.2 GHz

```
sequential: time    6.52 s
2 threads: time     3.66 s
2 threads + SSE:    3.75 s
```

I used OpenMP because it makes this easy.  Each thread in OpenMP runs over effectively

```
lowerBound = N*part/CORES;
upperBound = N*(part + 1)/CORES;
```

(note that that is slightly different than your definition. Your definition can give the wrong result due to rounding for some values of `N` since you divide by `CORES` first.)

As to the SIMD version. <s>It's not much faster probably due it being memory bandwidth bound</s> . It's probably not really faster because GCC already vectroizes the loop.

The most optimal solution is much more complicated. You need to use [loop tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling) and reorder the elements within tiles to get the optimal performance. I don't have time to do that today.

Here is the code I used:

```
//c99 -O3 -fopenmp -Wall foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <omp.h>

void gemm(float * restrict a, float * restrict b, float * restrict c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                c[i*n+j] += a[i*n+k]*b[k*n+j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void gemm_tlp(float * restrict a, float * restrict b, float * restrict c, int n) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                c[i*n+j] += a[i*n+k]*b[k*n+j];
            }
        }
    }
}   

void gemm_tlp_simd(float * restrict a, float * restrict b, float * restrict c, int n) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
            __m128 a4 = _mm_set1_ps(a[i*n+k]);
            for(int j=0; j<n; j+=4) {
                __m128 c4 = _mm_load_ps(&c[i*n+j]);
                __m128 b4 = _mm_load_ps(&b[k*n+j]);
                c4 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a4,b4),c4);
                _mm_store_ps(&c[i*n+j], c4);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 2048;
    float *a = _mm_malloc(n*n * sizeof *a, 64);
    float *b = _mm_malloc(n*n * sizeof *b, 64);
    float *c1 = _mm_malloc(n*n * sizeof *c1, 64);
    float *c2 = _mm_malloc(n*n * sizeof *c2, 64);
    float *c3 = _mm_malloc(n*n * sizeof *c2, 64);
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++) a[i] = 1.0*i;
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++) b[i] = 1.0*i;
    memset(c1, 0, n*n * sizeof *c1);
    memset(c2, 0, n*n * sizeof *c2);
    memset(c3, 0, n*n * sizeof *c3);
    double dtime;

    dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
    gemm(a,b,c1,n);
    dtime += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("time %f\n", dtime);

    dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
    gemm_tlp(a,b,c2,n);
    dtime += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("time %f\n", dtime);

    dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
    gemm_tlp_simd(a,b,c3,n);
    dtime += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("time %f\n", dtime);
    printf("error %d\n", memcmp(c1,c2, n*n*sizeof *c1));
    printf("error %d\n", memcmp(c1,c3, n*n*sizeof *c1));
}
```

Comment: @ Z boston . thak you 'Z boston'. I tried your code in Dev-c++ environment on Windows 7 with Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2200  @ 2.20GHz and 3 GB ram. At first I compiled with -fopenmp -std=c99 commands. The times I get are: 134.909, 133.115, and 52.494 respectively for sequential, 2 threads and 2 threads + sse. Then I tried with -O3 -fopenmp -Wall -Std=c99 commands. I get following times: 10.576, 9.657, and 9.15. The speed up of threaded+sse of last try over sequential in my computer is 1.09x, and your speed up is approx. 4x. Is this difference in speed up related to the CPU architecture?

Comment: @Zboston. It is a question for me that what is the effect of -O3 flag on threaded+sse version?

Comment: @estjop, it's pointless to measure performance without optimization enabled. I added times for a system similar to yours. I don't know why you're not seeing any benefit from threading. You should do a little test to maker sure you're getting two threads with OpenMP.

Comment: @Zboston, I tested code, I am sure that I'm getting two threads, but it seems speed up is not enough! This time my speed up was 1.34x. I have to test code on different computer. Could this problem be related to my compiler (Dev-c++, is tested with both MinGW GCC 4.7.2 and TDM-GCC 4.9.2)?

Comment: @estjop, I don't know about your compiler. I tested this with GCC 4.9 with Linux Kernel 3.18 64-bit. Are you compiling in 64-bit mode?  What happens if you add `-m64` to your options?

Comment: @Z boston, my hardware is 32-bit. I compiled with '-m65', compiler sends this message: 'sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in'.

Comment: @estjop,  you need to tell your compiler to use SSE instead of x87 for floating point. I would use `gcc -std=c99 -O3 -fopenmp -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -Wall foo.c`.  The options `-mfpmath=sse -msse2` tell GCC to use SSE instead of x87 and to enable SSE2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the threads are sharing `__m128 mmx*` variables, you probably defined them global/static. You must be getting wrong results in your X array too. Define `__m128 mmx*` variables inside `threadedSIMDMatMul` function scope and it will run much faster.

```
void threadedSIMDMatMul(void* params)
{
    __m128 mmx0, mmx1, mmx2, mmx3, mmx4;
    // rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are global. But I've checked results of different versions, results are same as sequential.

Comment: @estjop Really? I'm getting results similar to Z boston - multi-threaded version is faster than sequential, SIMD in this form does not add any benefit.

Comment: @estjop: The correctness of your results depends on the compiler optimizing away any stores/loads to the `mmx[0-8]` global variables.  If you ever modify the code in a way that spills a register to memory, then your code is suddenly not thread-safe anymore.