# Matrix multiplication speeds in R as fast as in Python?

Tags: python, r, numpy, rcpp, matrix-multiplication

I am experiencing substantially slower matrix multiplication in R as compared to python. This is for large matrices. For example (in python):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(4112, 23050).astype('float32')
B = np.random.rand(23050, 2500).astype('float32')

%timeit np.dot(A, B)

1 loops, best of 3: 1.09 s per loop
```

Here is the equivalent multiplication in R (takes almost 10x longer):

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(4112*23050), ncol = 23050)
B <- matrix(rnorm(23050*2500), ncol = 2500)

system.time(A %*% B)

user    system  elapsed 
72.032   1.048   9.444
```

**How can I achieve matrix multiplication speeds in R that are comparable to what is standard with python?**

### What I Have Already Tried:

**1)** Part of the descrepancy seems to be that python supports float32 whereas R only uses numeric, which is similar to (the same as?) float64. For example, the same python commands as above except with float64 takes twice as long (but still 5x slower than R):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(4112, 23050).astype('float64')
B = np.random.rand(23050, 2500).astype('float64')

%timeit np.dot(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.24 s per loop
```

**2)** I am using the openBLAS linear algebra back-end for R.

**3)** RcppEigen as detailed in answer to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923787/fast-large-matrix-multiplication-in-r) (see link for test.cpp file). The multiplication is about twice as fast in "user" time, but 3x slower in the more critical elapsed time as it only uses 1 of 8 threads.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("test.cpp")

A <- matrix(rnorm(4112*23050), nrow = 4112)
B <- matrix(rnorm(23050*2500), ncol = 2500)

system.time(res <- eigenMatMult(A, B))
user    system  elapsed 
29.436   0.056  29.551
```

Comment: What OS? http://simplystatistics.org/2016/01/21/parallel-blas-in-r/ ; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf  . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025866/parallel-linear-algebra-for-multicore-system claims OpenBLAS is multithreaded, so ... ??

Comment: PS I was a little annoyed that you deleted and reposted, but it seems [that's actually OK](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253438/is-deleting-a-question-and-posting-a-new-one-with-issues-fixed-acceptable) since you improved your question.

Comment: Ubuntu. `%*%` and Armadillo matrix multiplication (which provided no benefit over `%*%`) use all my cores but Eigen does not.

Comment: Maybe see this on Eigen: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Thanks for the suggestion: I just tried adding `Eigen::setNbThreads(8);` in test.cpp on line before `Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;` but it still used a single thread.

Comment: by the way, I'm assuming your actual use-case involves dense matrices  -- if not then you should definitely be using sparse methods (e.g. `Matrix` package)

Comment: were compiler options (`-fopenmp`) set correctly ... ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker Yes use case involves dense matrices with similar dimensions to examples above.

Comment: @Ben Bolker How do I check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `MRO` and `python` with `anaconda` and the `MKL` BLAS. Here are my results for the same data generating process, i.e. `np.random.rand` (`'float64'`) or `rnorm` and identical dimensions (*average and standard deviation over 10 replications* ):

**Python:**

```
np.dot(A, B) # 1.3616 s (sd = 0.1776)
```

**R:**

```
Bt = t(B)
a = A %*% B # 2.0285 s (sd = 0.1897)
acp = tcrossprod(A, Bt) # 1.3098 s (sd = 0.1206)
identical(acp, a) # TRUE
```

Comment: so just to clarify/put your results in words, (1) the MRO/MKL BLAS brings the timing within a factor of 2, (2) using `tcrossprod`gains another factor of 2, making the Python & R timings approx equal? It would be worth knowing the platform (OS) on which you did this

Comment: Yes, that's it. The platform is Ubuntu 14.04. I think the setup, i.e. `anaconda` (MRO/python 2.7) + `MKL`, makes sure that the comparison is fair...

Comment: And just to state the obvious:  MKL can be obtained independently of either of those two products, and still be provided for both languages.

Comment: Just a side note that MKL does not support hyperthreading ([reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rropen/h_q_HUsQM2s/_DXisD8hAQAJ)). It will only use 4 of my 8 hyperthreads because my computer only has 4 physical cores.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly tangential, but too long for a comment I think.  To check whether the relevant compiler flags (e.g. `-fopenmp`) are set, use `sourceCpp("testeigen.cpp",verbose=TRUE)`.

On my system, this showed that the OpenMP flags are *not* defined by default.

I did this to enable them (adapted from [here](http://www.lindonslog.com/programming/r/rcpp/)):

```
library(Rcpp)
pkglibs <- "-fopenmp -lgomp"
pkgcxxflags <- "-fopenmp"
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS=pkglibs,PKG_CXXFLAGS=pkgcxxflags)
sourceCpp("testeigen.cpp",verbose=TRUE)
```

- Dirk Eddelbuettel [comments](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2013-August/006374.html) that he prefers to set the compiler flags in `~/.R/Makevars`.
- The example I took this from called the internal `Rcpp:::RcppLdFlags` and `Rcpp:::RcppCxxFlags` functions and prepended the results to the flags given above; this seems not to be necessary (?)

Comment: We have a so-called plugin for OpenMP, as we do for C++11, C++14, ... and related switches.  See eg [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/R/Attributes.R#L484-L488) and IIRC the Rcpp Gallery pieces on OpenMP all show it too.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this did allow for parallel matrix multiplication with RcppEigen. Surprisingly, the benefit was minor (less than 1s faster).